# NoneType Error Finding Text in anchor using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `Selenium` then `BS` to get stock tickers from a finviz screener page.

I can drill down to the anchors I need, but when I try and extract the text I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.
```

This method has always worked on static pages that don't require Selenium.

Relevant part of the code to get the anchors from the Table:

```
for row in searchSource.findAll("tr"):
    ticker_element = row.find("a", class_="screener-link-primary")
    print(ticker_element)
```

will give me a list of items like this

```
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=AFRM&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">AFRM</a>
```

but

```
ticker = ticker_element.text
```

or

```
.content[0] produces AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

What do i need to do to get the 4 letter AFRM from ticker_element in this example?

Answer (score 1):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

Select your elements more specific, because actually you find all `<tr>`, also these that do not contain any `<a>`. So instead try to select by:

```
for row in soup.select('#screener-table table tr:has(a.screener-link-primary)'):
    print(row.select_one('a.screener-link-primary').text)
```

---

Alternative to scrape tables use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
    
df = pd.read_html(
    requests.get('https://finviz.com/screener.ashx', headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}).text,
    match='Company'
)[4]

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df[1:].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example worked. I don't think Pandas would work as these pages are served using JS (hence the need to use Selenium).

I also found that I needed to add an html parser definition to BeautifulSoup() as it was throwing up issues

Answer (score 0):

you can use assert to check that it is not none

```
for row in searchSource.findAll("tr"):
    ticker_element = row.find("a", class_="screener-link-primary")
    assert ticker_element != None
    print(ticker_element)
```

if I use the simple code, it runs normally.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
k = '''<a class="screener-link-primary" href="quote.ashx?t=AFRM&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">AFRM</a>'''
p = soup(k)
kk = p.text
```